# How can I configuration WCF with static IP Address?

Tags: c#, wcf

I tried and googled many times, but can't solve this problem. Please help me!

These are my pictures

[image: this is my web.config]

[image: this is my IIS]

When I try to browse the SVC file, it throws the error :

> XML Parsing Error : no element found.

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please don't post pics of  your code.  Post it inline as _text_

Comment: You should put code directly in your question rather than including a screenshot.

Also, are you missing a closing tag on system.serviceModel?

Answer (score 0):

Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address (for example, http://localhost/MyService.svc) can lead to errors in the deployment of the service if the endpoint address does not point to the IIS-application that hosts the service exposing the endpoint. Using relative endpoint addresses for hosted services avoids these potential conflicts. You could refer [Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx).
So, to achieve your requirement, use relative address, and host it in IIS, then you could use current machine IP to view your service.